# How to call the JSP function and send the parameter using the function

Tags: jsp

I have two files which is Form.jsp and Util.jsp

What I want to do is I want to substitute the `<%=sType%>` attribute with a function call name `checkParam` and pass the parameter

Form.jsp

sType is a variable

```
sType=request.getParameter("type")!=nullrequest.getParameter("type").toString():"";

<form name="myFrm" method=post action="frmAction.jsp?type=<%=checkParam(sType)%>">
```

Util.jsp

```
public String checkParam(String mParam)
{
     //mycode
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<%=sType%>"> is jsp code, right? then why is it in a .html file? JSP files are rendered by the server and since can process java code, hence the name Java Server Pages. HTML files are served as resources and no such rendering is done on server side. If you want the form to be configured dynamically use either a .JSP file to reside the form or use an ajax call and javascript/jquery to set the action parameter manually.

Even if you used a .JSP to render the form i think the code should be written with a place holder.

```
<form name="myFrm" method=post action="frmAction.jsp?type=${sType}">
```

If you are using JSP use standard tag libraries. Coding like <%=sType%> is bad practice, as of my understanding.

According to the edit I think the statement should be

```
sType=(request.getParameter("type")!=null) ? request.getParameter("type").toString():"";
```

Comment: I'm sorry it is not a html file..It is a jsp file

Comment: how do you call the method? is sType the returned string of method checkParam? can you post where you set the sType variable?

Comment: Okay..I will edit the code and paste my attempt .You can check after that.Hold On

Comment: I had edit the code.Can you check whether my attempt is true or false?

Comment: still confusing, what are you trying to achieve? If type parameter is not null assign it to sType and if it is null assign a default value to type? Am i correct? edited answer, pls check.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as accepted then? :) I am new and would like to earn points :)